# It's about iOS messaging

Tags: ios

When I read source code, I found this:

```
self[@"__NSCFString"] = @"RETableViewCell";
self[@"NSString"] = @"RETableViewCell";
self[@"RETableViewItem"] = @"RETableViewCell";
self[@"RERadioItem"] = @"RETableViewOptionCell";
```

What concerns me is that what is the use of "[]" here, since "[]" is often used to send a message to a receiver instead of containing an object? And please be noticed that the "self" is not a dictionary, it inherits from NSObject instead.

This has concerned me for days. Anyone who can help me out? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Google for "Key value coding".

Comment: Can you show me more details? I've look it up in KVO and KVC in Apple Doc, but still find nowhere to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is a class that overrides:

`- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx`

and

`- (void)setObject:(id)anObject atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index` to support the subscript operator. See: `http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html` for subscripting.

Comment: What you said is exactly right ! I've read the source code and learnt that "self" did overrides the two methods. Thank you very much!